# Is there a way to calculate a gradient of dissimilarity across multiple sites using presence/absence data?

Tags: r, indexing, genetics

I’ve been trying to come up with a metric for species (dis)similarity for fish in a series based on presence or absence data that gives a value of 1 or 0 for each lake. From my research, it seems like a Multi-site dissimilarity index using Jaccard index would work best, as single-site presence/absence for each lake doesn't need nestedness or special turnover caveats. Calculating a measure of beta-diversity in R through 'betapart' gives an overall value of 0.86. Now I want to come up with a value of (dis)similarity for each site, that I can then use to plug into an RDA as a continuous variable. Is there a method of calculating site-specific dissimilarity? The closest thing I can come up with is taking beta diversity across all sites =0.86, then calculating a measure of how many species are present in each lake divided by 0.86, kind of using a makeshift Jaccard index formula. For example site 1 would be =(1/7)/0.86; although I don't know if this violates any assumptions. Below is the data that I used.

```
        Species1 Species2 Species3 Species4 Species5 Species6 Species7
Site 1      1       0         0       0         0        0       0
Site 2      1       1         0       0         0        0       1
Site 3      1       1         1       1         1        1       1
Site 4      1       0         0       0         0        0       0
Site 5      1       0         0       0         0        0       1
Site 6      1       0         0       0         0        0       0
Site 7      1       0         1       0         0        0       0
Site 8      1       0         0       0         0        0       0
Site 9      1       0         0       0         0        0       0
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since this seems to be more of a statistical question I encourage you to psot this question at Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/